# Adding card to Laravel Jetstream / Livewire profile form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

I'm attempting to add a new profile section to the default laravel jetstream profile view. I've created a new livewire component called `SetContactPreferences` and am calling it from `resources/views/profile/show.blade.php` by adding:

```
@livewire('profile.set-contact-preferences')
```

The form I created shows up as expected in the profile as a new card.

However, I'm unclear on what the submit action should look like. [The docs say](https://jetstream.laravel.com/2.x/features/profile-management.html) that the form will submit the current authenticated user as well as the form input, so I created a method in my component like:

```
public function setContactPreferences($user, $input) {
    dd($input);
}
```

I added `<x-jet-form-section submit="setShowingPreferences">` to the top of the `set-contact-preferences.blade.php` file.

Submitting the form throws the following error:

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Unable to resolve dependency [Parameter #0 [ <required> $user ]] in class App\Http\Livewire\Profile\SetContactPreferences
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way it works in Jetstream is that when the `user profile information form` is submitted, that submission is processed by the `update` method on the `ProfileInformationController` located at `Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\ProfileInformationController`.

The `update` method expects two parameters, a `Request` object and an `UpdatesUserProfileInformation` (which is an instance of `App\Actions\Fortify\UpdateUserProfileInformation`), both of which are injected from the service container.

Jetstream obtains the current user from the `Request` object using `$request->user()` which is then passed to the `UpdatesUserProfileInformation` along with any form input using `$request->input()`.

If you are not concerned with other people updating user profile information (for example a system admin), you can type-hint a `Request` object in your method signature and it will automatically be injected:

```
public function setContactPreferences(Request $request)
{
    // Dump the currently authenticated user
    dd($request->user());
}
```

Alternatively you could provide your component with a `User` for scenarios where you might want to update the information of a user that is not the currently authenticated user.

```
public User $user;

public function setContactPreferences()
{
    dd($this->user);
}
```

Then passing a `User` to the component:

```
@livewire('profile.set-contact-preferences', ['user' => Auth::user()])
```

or

```
@livewire('profile.set-contact-preferences', ['user' => User::find(1)])
```